# What can I do to prevent MySQL using up all RAM and SWAP in Debian 10?

Tags: linux, debian, mysql

I am using MySQL 8.0.18 in a group replication (multi-master) infrastructure. There are currently 4 master servers connected to each other and everything seems to be working fine but over the course of around 2 weeks all mysqld process on all servers uses up all the swap. ram usage stays at 800Mb as I suspect innodb_log_buffer_size is doing its job.

**Server Specs:**

Debian 10

1Gb RAM

3GB SWAP

20GB ssd

**Mysql.cnf:**

max_connections=20

innodb_log_buffer_size=800M

key_buffer_size=50M

super_read_only=off

gtid_mode = ON

enforce_gtid_consistency = ON

master_info_repository = TABLE

relay_log_info_repository = TABLE

binlog_checksum = NONE

log_slave_updates = ON

log_bin = binlog

binlog_format = ROW

transaction_write_set_extraction = XXHASH64

loose-group_replication_bootstrap_group = OFF

loose-group_replication_start_on_boot = OFF

loose-group_replication_ssl_mode = REQUIRED

loose-group_replication_recovery_use_ssl = 1

loose-group_replication_unreachable_majority_timeout=80

loose-group-replication-autorejoin-tries=2015

loose-group-replication-transaction-size-limit=0

**Related OS config:**

vm.swappiness=5

How do I make mysql stop using so much swap?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter that configure the InnoDB available space in RAM for data is [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size). If didn't set, the default one is 128MB. This is the main parameter for InnoDB, normally the people recommend to set it up to 80% of your total memory.

The [innodb_log_buffer_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size) is a important one too but is related to the actions happening in the moment, written to the disk in chunks of 16MB to avoid data corruptions when they aren't still writing definitively.

There is a lot of other configurations for memory related to other **storage engines**, but in the 8 version, the majority, or totally, is InnoDB.

Probably **swappiness** is high because you database are not allowed to use the RAM its needs - **innodb_buffer_pool_size** is 128MB.

Remove **innodb_log_buffer_size** and in it's place put **innodb_buffer_pool_size**.